# Change background on FloatingActionButton?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I am trying to set the background of a FAB to a different color in XML. I know I could do this in code, but that would also require a lot of inconvenient refactoring on my part.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="#F38E1B"
    android:id="@+id/fab"/>
```

[image]

For some reason, the background stays blue when it should be orange. I have tried setting the background to a drawable as well but that yields the same results.

Is this a bug or am I just missing something?

Comment: You can try it : setBackgroundColor(int color) from the official documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html

Comment: @FlavienBert I did, and I got the same result. And as I said, doing this through code would require a lot of refactoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. Turns out you do have to set the background to a drawable (thanks @Nilesh), but there was something wrong with the drawable I was setting it to. I used this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/al_color_accent_orange_light"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

as my drawable and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

I also tried to use the same approach as you and was getting the same result. My solution was to was to this:

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/yourColor</item>
```

in my application theme.

However, this color will also be used in all your widgets.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but this is for a fairly large app so I don't think that's an option.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. This is how I solve my issue: I just create a new theme to my button.

My FAB xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
      ...
      android:theme="@style/MapButton"/>
```

My new theme in style.xml:

```
<style name="MapButton" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</item></style>
```

I created a new theme based on my App's theme and changed only the color I wanted.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As `FloatingActionButton` extends `ImageView`

see this [link](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.java)

Also see the **line no 76**

they are getting `background` as `drawable` and you are setting the `color`

so I don't think you can change it using `color`.

try setting `drawable` as background

see this [link](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/res/values/styles.xml) and **line no 20**

Answer (score 1):

in xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    ...
    app:backgroundTint="@color/background_tint"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />
```

in code

```
mFlaotsetBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.Blue))
```