# How to change FAB background color

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am using Floating Action Button and I want to change the background color.

Here is my code

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btnfab"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/search" />
```

Here is the code I am using to try and achieve this:

```
1- android:background="@color/mycolor"
2- android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
```

I am also getting corners on my FAB as shown in image. How should I remove those corner shadows?

[image]

Comment: add please dependencies from `build.gradle`

Comment: I didnt add any fab dependencies. I just use fab by creating BlankActivity then copy and paste it in my project. It use theme color of my project

Comment: Check this post regarding the "corners" of the FAB: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332587/how-to-fix-shadow-on-scaled-floatingactionbutton-using-support-library-23/34345100#34345100

Comment: @Ritesh I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can remove problematic shadow by adding this attributes to your `FloatingActionButton`:

```
app:borderWidth="0dp"
app:elevation="6dp"
```

There is no background color for `FloatingActionButton`. You change this component color by:

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/YOURCOLOR"
```

Remember to have in your parent layout following line:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Answer (score 9):

Declare following in your app style:

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/yourColor</ item>
```

cheers

Comment: While this will work, it will affect more than just FAB. So I'd recommend a different solution.

Comment: While this may not be a good solution for everyone (if they want their `colorAccent` to be different than the FAB), in my case it is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 7):

First create a style in your styles.xml:

```
<style name="PrimaryActionButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Then set the theme of your fab to this style:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_white_24dp"
android:theme="@style/PrimaryActionButton"
app:fabSize="normal"
app:rippleColor="@color/colorAccent" />
```

You can see full descrption in:
[Android: Floating Action button](https://medium.com/android-bits/android-floating-action-button-37e81c5e4fe6)

Comment: This way you can support APIs less than 21. While the accepted answer doesn't do so.

Comment: I agree... For API's less than 21, this is the solution.  This also works on newer API's so this is the most versatile answer.

Comment: This is the best solution

Answer (score 6):

Please update your android support and android material design libraries in `build.gradle`.

(Add please your build.gradle file above)

According to these sites:

- [[CodePath] Floating Action Buttons](https://guides.codepath.com/android/floating-action-buttons),
- [[Big Nerd Ranch] Floating Action Buttons in Android Lollipop](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/floating-action-buttons-in-android-l/)

and [Android Developers reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) you should use only:

```
   android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
```

As I remember, this shadow is well-know problem for Floating action buttons, so please take a look at these additional libraries:

http://android-arsenal.com/tag/173

which may help you to replace this broken element.

Check also:

- [Change color of Floating Action Button from Appcompat 22.2.0 programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30966222/change-color-of-floating-action-button-from-appcompat-22-2-0-programmatically)
- [Change background on FloatingActionButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873595/change-background-on-floatingactionbutton)

Hope it help.